# Выборка по одному массиву из второго

Tags: php

Чет я запутался, помогите с алгоритмом
есть два массива

```
Array
(
    [4] => 0
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 1
    [25] => 1
    [23] => 0
)
```

и

```
Array
(
    ['21'] => on
    ['23'] => on
)
```

Надо в случае совпадения ключей, в первый массив записать 1, а все остальные значения, ключи  которых не совпадают с ключами массива 2 - заполнить 0

Записать у меня получилось, перебирая второй массив, и делая

```
$k = intval(str_replace('\'', '', $k));
```

затем

```
$array1[k] = 1;
```

но почему-то не могу догнать как заполнить остальные значения первого массива 0
а городить кучу форичей как-то не хочется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr1 = Array
(
    [4] => 0
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 1
    [25] => 1
    [23] => 0
);

$arr2 = Array
(
    ['21'] => on
    ['23'] => on
);


foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){
    if (array_key_exists($k, $arr1)) {
        $arr1[$k] = 1;
    }else{
        $arr1[$k] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = [
  4 => 0,
  20 => 0,
  21 => 1,
  25 => 1,
  23 => 0,
];


$arr2 = [
  '21' => 'on',
  '23' => 'on'
];


array_walk($arr1, function(&$value, $key) use ($arr2){
  $value = array_key_exists($key, $arr2) ? 1 : 0;
});

// $arr1 = array(5) {
//   [4] => int(0)
//   [20] => int(0)
//   [21] => int(1)
//   [25] => int(0)
//   [23] => int(1)
// }
```